# VBA code string to cell not working - run time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm trying to accomplish something very simple. Actually it used to run normally but when I changed to windows 7 + Office 2013 it just stopped working.

The following line in `VBA` won't work:

```
Worksheets("Charts").Cells(2, 7) = "=" & "23,45" & "/PL!C" & 2
```

Charts is an existent sheet of mine and PL is another existent sheet.

If I add watch to the right hand side equation I get the following formula, which when pasted to the cell (manually) does work.

```
=23,45/PL!C2
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

I've looked into several run time error 1004 questions but none of them seem to either be the same issue or work for me. Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) with EN-US syntax or [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) with your regional locale settings.

```
Worksheets("Charts").Cells(2, 7).FORMULA = "=" & "23.45" & "/PL!C" & 2
Worksheets("Charts").Cells(2, 7).FORMULALOCAL = "=" & "23,45" & "/PL!C" & 2
```

VBA is very EN-US-centric as providing translation for all regional settings 'on-the-fly' would create a large overhead.