# Excel VBA: Application defined or object defined error using formula (COUNTIF)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying do some like this

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate

        If ws.Name <> "Estatística" Then
                Range("H9").Formula = "=COUNTIF(D9:D308;1)"
        End If
Next ws
```

But it gives the error "Application defined or object defined error". The same error doesn't happen if a use another formula, like "=SUM(H9:H13)" for example.

Comment: Also [VBA code string to cell not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319125/vba-code-string-to-cell-not-working-run-time-error-1004) and [Different languages issue when inserting formula from VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724156/different-languages-issue-when-inserting-formula-from-vba/35724386#35724386).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Range("H9").Formula = "=COUNTIF(D9:D308,1)"
```

Comment: Thanks! But why doesn't works with ";"?

Comment: @Nevallem I have noticed that sometimes when *VBA* deposits a formula, it needs to follow the USA formula standard even if you use a different standard for manual formula deposits.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you didn't suggest *trying* something, and added an explanation of why this is the solution. *Try this* is a suggestion, not an answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice/196191#196191

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that it would have been better to use the word "Use" rather than "Try"

Comment: It would also be better if you explain why it solves the problem, so that future users learn something when they read the answer. You can [edit] your post to improve it, as I'm sure you know. :-)